Performance issues using actionscript sockets class and serproxy
I'm working with an Adobe Animate project (as3) that accepts serial input from an external device. The data is in 4-byte ASCII strings terminated with \n. The 4-bytes of data are a 'frame number' used to position an image on an UHD (3840x2160) monitor via HDMI.
Serproxy is used to read the serial port and generate packets to be received using the as3 socket class. The serial data runs at 115200, N, 8, 1 and the TCP traffic is over localhost.
When sequential frame numbers are generated internally in the as3 script, motion is smooth and even. But when driven by the external frame numbers, which are themselves smoothly generated, the resulting motion suffers lags and skips.
The entire serproxy/sockets chain is opaque to me. I don't know how we might determine where the choppy response originates.
Can anyone suggest how we might debug this, or point to any known factors that could cause such an issue, or even better, avoid this interface altogether?
Thanks for reading!

Make an empty mock project that only receives the said data and outputs them with getTimer() info. If the reception happens at uneven intervals, the network part is to blame.

@Organis - thanks, we've tried that and it is really more ragged than I would expect. I'm not sure what next steps are though. It seems serproxy is the only way to accomplish the transfer of serial data into as3. I've heard of an "as3-arduino-connector" ANE, but no one seems to use it.

Can you send the instructions in advance? Like, to create a buffer to negate the network issues.

@Organis - We've tried using a buffer to take in the ragged events and pump them out against a clock (aka a time base corrector), but a buffer of sufficient length creates too much delay.

I don't know how you implemented this, but out of sheer common sense it shouldn't be that difficult just to wait, say, 1 second, and then start changing frames at precise intervals while the 1-sec buffer keeps network lags in check.

@Organis - What's missing is that this is real-time interactive. Response to user input must be (close to) immediate, and smoothly reactive.

Ah, makes sense. Then network lag is your reality.

Adobe Animate runs in a sandbox with no external connections allowed, so Serproxy or equivalent is required when using serial devices. Serproxy and Animate communicate through a TCP port on localhost.
But jitter, delays and uncertainty somewhere in the chain make this setup unsuited for near-realtime use.
We switched to Unity, which allows direct serial connections, and our issues vanished.
